# Enumerate list - numbers with prefix

Tags: lists, enumerate

How to make enumerate list format numbers like this:

> REG/001 (content)
>
> REG/002 (content)
>
> REG/003 (content)

I already managed to do the following:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{REG/\arabic*},leftmargin=*]
\item content
\end{enumerate}
```

using

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
```

but I don't know how to add leading zeros.

Comment: See the answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108224/3954

Comment: Trying to change that code to adjust it to my needs gives me errors by compiler. I started learnig Latex this evening and it is rather difficult to me at this point, could you provide any sample?

Comment: Please post your attempt as a fully compilable (if the syntax errors were corrected) document.

Comment: @user1091733 sure! Please see my answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\def\threedigits#1{%
  \ifnum#1<100 0\fi
  \ifnum#1<10 0\fi
  \number#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\textbf{REG/\protect\threedigits{\theenumi}}},leftmargin=*]
\item content
\item content
\item content
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here is another variant of the same concept that makes use of `\AddEnumerateCounter`

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\def\threedigits#1{\expandafter\@threedigits\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@threedigits#1{%
  \ifnum#1<100 0\fi
  \ifnum#1<10 0\fi
  \number#1}
\makeatother
\AddEnumerateCounter{\threedigits}{\@threedigits}{100}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=REG/\threedigits*,leftmargin=*]
\item This is an  item.
\item Another item.
\item Here is another item.
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]