# A leading zero in the enumerate environment

Tags: lists, enumerate

I need to make my Enumerate look like this:

> REQ/Text/001
>   REQ/Text/002
>   ...

What i can do is this:

> REQ/Text/1
>   ...

But how can i add leading Zeros? I tried the answer in:
[Enumerate list - numbers with prefix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108236/enumerate-list-numbers-with-prefix)
but it doesnt work. It brings me something like:

> REQ/Text/1!100 01!10 001

but the exclamation mark is turned around.
Sorry for my bad English, im from Germany.

Thanks.

Edit:
A minimal Code example is:

```
    \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

    \usepackage{german,epsfig,longtable,graphicx,fullpage,float}%

    \usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} % Umlaute (Windows)

    \usepackage{enumitem}

    \def\threedigits#1{% 
    \ifnum#1<100 0\fi 
    \ifnum#1<10 0\fi 
    \number#1}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{RQ/Gru/\threedigits{\theenumi}}, leftmargin = *]
        \item \label{anfo:norm:S1}  
            \item \label{anfo:norm:S2}  
            \item \label{anfo:norm:S3}  
            \item \label{anfo:norm:S4}
    \end{enumerate}

    \end{document}
```

This minimal example produces the Error.

Error Messages are:

Missing number, threated as zero

Missing = inserted for \ifnum

Comment: Post your code. Using the answer in the question you linked works for me.. Maybe you forget the `\usepackage{enumitem}` in your preamble.

Comment: I used the enumitem Package before, i get Error Messages like _! Missing Number threathed as zero. ...\threedigits{\theenumi}_ and _Missing = inserted for \ifnum_. In my preamble i have '\usepackage{enumitem}

\def\threedigits#1{%
  \ifnum#1<100 0\fi
  \ifnum#1<10 0\fi
  \number#1}'

Comment: Sorry for the bad Format, its my first Question on StackExchange

Comment: not only these lines, provide a [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Edit your question not add the code in a comment, thnaks

Comment: You may want to have a look at [How to incorporate counter in list label](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118452/5049). (This question may be a duplicate?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss the `\protect` command before using the `\threedigits` one.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{german,epsfig,longtable,graphicx,fullpage,float}%

\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} % Umlaute (Windows)

\usepackage{enumitem}

\def\threedigits#1{% 
\ifnum#1<100 0\fi 
\ifnum#1<10 0\fi 
\number#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\textbf{RQ/Gru/\protect\threedigits{\theenumi}}}, leftmargin = *]
    \item \label{anfo:norm:S1}  
        \item \label{anfo:norm:S2}  
        \item \label{anfo:norm:S3}  
        \item \label{anfo:norm:S4}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]