# Whitesace in Leading Zeroes in Enumerate Environment

Tags: numbering, lists, enumerate

I've been trying to make an `enumerate` environment with this format: "N09 P###.", where ### is a list of zero-padded items from 1 to 200 (001-200). I was using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132542/236070) to help me with this, but it puts a space between "P" and "###". While trying to find another solution, I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194643/236070) that allows for 2 zero-padded digits, but it doesn't work when I try to convert it to three digits. If anyone can help me with this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Image of what my PDF currently looks like:

[image: Current Output, "N09 P ###." format]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is based on your  [first link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132542/161015).

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\def\threedigits#1{% 
    \ifnum#1<100 0\fi 
    \ifnum#1<10 0\fi 
    \number#1.} % <<<<<<<<<<<< dot added 

\begin{document}    
    
    \begin{enumerate}[label={\textbf{N09\ P\protect\threedigits{\theenumi}}}, leftmargin = *]%<<<<<<<<<< changed
        \item 
        \item   
        \item
        \item 
        \item 
        \item   
        \item
        \item
        \item 
        \item   
    \end{enumerate}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: a]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'd register a new numeric representation and define a new environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\arabicthreedigits}[1]{\expandafter\@arabicthreedigits\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\@arabicthreedigits}[1]{%
  \ifnum#1<100 0\fi
  \ifnum#1<10 0\fi
  \number#1%
}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\arabicthreedigits}{\@arabicthreedigits}{000}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{doubleenumerate}[1]
 {\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries N#1 P\arabicthreedigits*,leftmargin=7em]}
 {\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}    

Some text before the enumerate environment
some text before the enumerate environment
some text before the enumerate environment
\begin{doubleenumerate}{09}
  \item\label{x} abc
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
  \item
\end{doubleenumerate}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the first part is to have a progressive number, you can do as follows.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\arabicthreedigits}[1]{\expandafter\@arabicthreedigits\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\@arabicthreedigits}[1]{%
  \ifnum#1<100 0\fi
  \ifnum#1<10 0\fi
  \number#1%
}
\newcommand{\arabictwodigits}[1]{\expandafter\@arabictwodigits\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\@arabictwodigits}[1]{%
  \ifnum#1<10 0\fi
  \number#1%
}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\arabicthreedigits}{\@arabicthreedigits}{000}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\arabictwodigits}{\@arabictwodigits}{00}
\makeatother

\newcounter{doubleenumerate}
\newenvironment{doubleenumerate}
 {%
  \stepcounter{doubleenumerate}%
  \begin{enumerate}[
    label=\bfseries N\arabictwodigits{doubleenumerate} P\arabicthreedigits*,
    leftmargin=7em
  ]%
 }
 {\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}    

Some text before the enumerate environment
some text before the enumerate environment
some text before the enumerate environment
\begin{doubleenumerate}
  \item\label{x} abc
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
  \item
\end{doubleenumerate}
Some text before the enumerate environment
some text before the enumerate environment
some text before the enumerate environment
\begin{doubleenumerate}
  \item
  \item 
\end{doubleenumerate}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]