# Add leading zero to the items listed by a custom etaremune and enumerate

Tags: lists, enumerate

How can I add leading zeros in the items that are listed by the packages `etaremune` and `enumerate`? For example, I would like to have the labels to be:

```
A01, A02, A03, ..., A09, A10
```

Here is an example code. How can I add the leading zeros locally and globally?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etaremune}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{nosep} % To remove the spacing


\begin{document}
First list

\renewcommand*{\labelenumi}{A\theenumi.}
\begin{etaremune}[topsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,] 
    \item item 10
    \item item 09
    \item item 08
    \item item 07
    \item item 06
    \item item 05
    \item item 04
    \item item 03
    \item item 02
    \item item 01
\end{etaremune}

Second list
\begin{enumerate}[label={M\arabic*.}]
    \item item 01
    \item item 02
\end{enumerate}

Third list
\begin{enumerate}[label={M\arabic*.}, resume]
    \item item 03
    \item item 04
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Here is [image]the output:

Comment: At least related: [How to incorporate counter in list label](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118445/5049) and [Enumerate list - numbers with prefix](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108236/enumerate-list-numbers-with-prefix)

Answer (score 8):

[**Edit** I'm editting this to make the solution clearer, inlight of the evolution of the both the question and its solution. As a result, the comments below may not make much sense...]

The code below makes it possible to do what you want using just the [enumitem package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). In particular,  [etaremune](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etaremune) is no longer needed because we trick enumerate into behaving like an etaremune environment using enumitem.

The code uses enumitem's `\AddEnumerateCounter` command to define two new counters: `\PaddingUp` and `\PaddingDown`. Both counters pad item numbers with a `0` if the counter is less than 10. The `\PaddingDown` counter has the extra feature of surreptitiously *decreasing* the item counter by one (it actually decreases it by two so that when the counter is next incremented the net effect is that it will have decreased by one).

The `\PaddingUp` and `\PaddingDown` counters can be used like any of the standard enumitem counter macros. Consequently,

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=Up\PaddingUp*.]
...
\end{enumerate}
```

creates an enumerate environment with item labels `Up01.`, `Up02.`, ... whereas

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=Down\PaddingDown*.,start=10]
...
\end{enumerate}
```

creates an enumerate environment with item labels `Down10.`, `Down09.`, ...

The following code prodcuces the OP's requested output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\AddEnumerateCounter{\PaddingUp}{\two@digits}{A00}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\PaddingDown}{\two@digits}{A00}
\newcommand\PaddingUp[1]{\expandafter\two@digits\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand\PaddingDown[1]{\PaddingUp{#1}\addtocounter{#1}{-2}}
\makeatother

\setlist[enumerate]{nosep,label=M\PaddingUp*.} % To remove the spacing
\newlist{etaremune}{enumerate}{1}% one level of nesting
\setlist[etaremune]{nosep,label=A\PaddingDown*.}

\begin{document}

First list
\begin{etaremune}[start=10]
    \item item 10
    \item item 09
    \item item 08
    \item item 07
    \item item 06
    \item item 05
    \item item 04
    \item item 03
    \item item 02
    \item item 01
\end{etaremune}

Second list
\begin{enumerate}
    \item item 01
    \item item 02
\end{enumerate}

Third list
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item item 03
    \item item 04
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

For good measure, the code above defines an `etaremune` enviroment with the `nosep` option. This is possibly misleading, however, because the decreasing counters are given by setting the label to `label=\PaddingDown*.` Above, this is done using `setlist`. Note that it is necessay to explicitly set the starting value of the item counters in an `etaremune` environment. If you don't set a starting value then they will start from 1, which is probably not what you want.

Finally, perhaps I should point out that it is easy to change the letters etc labelling these environments as you use them. For example, to change them to use `P`'s and `Q`'s you would write:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=P\PaddingDown*.]% item -> P#. going up
    \item item 01 \item item 02
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=Q\PaddingUp*.]% item -> P#. going down
    \item item 01 \item item 02
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly. How can I do the same thing for `enumerate`? The code you kindly posted only works for `etaremune` and the ones in my document that are using `enumerate` are intact and no leading zeros are printed. Can this be modified such that it works for `enumerate` as well:  `\begin{enumerate}[label={M\arabic*.},]
 \item item 01
 \item item 02
\end{enumerate}`

Comment: @A2009 Actually, this is a "bug" in my fix in that it will also modify how the counters are printed in an `enumerate` environment. Luckily you want this! To have this work you need to put the `\renewcommand\theenumi...` in your preamble at the *top* of your document. I think that the `eumerate` environments for which this is failing must be before this commend in your document. Is this correct?

Comment: Actually, it is already at the top of the document.

Comment: Oh, I see from your comment that you must be using the `enumitem` package, so the reason why this doesn't work is that the `label={M\arabic*.}` is redefining the labels...will see if there is a good way to get this to work in the `enumitem` framework.

Comment: If you only want your modified `\theenumi` to have an effect locally, place it in the environment before for the first `\item`.

Comment: @A2009 I've added some code to make this work with `enumitem`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Unfortunately I have many lists whose labels are customozied. Some of them start with M, some start with A, C, T, P, J. Can I have your thoughts on this?

Comment: @A2009 The code above will work fine for you then. I have redefine the `etaremune` environment using the features of `enumitem`. You can define your labels at the start of the environment using `label=M\ZoerPadded*.` for increasing conters and `label=A\zeroPadded*.` for decreasing counters replacing `A` and `M` s needed

Comment: Instead of `\@PaddingUp` and `\@PaddingDown` (which are the same, anyway) you could use LaTeX's `\two@digits`. Is there a reason you use TeX's `\def` instead of LaTeX's `\newcommand`?

Comment: @cgnieder I didn't know about `\two@digits`. Of course, it's equivalent to what's above, but it does shorten the commands so I'll edit. Will also change to using `\newcommand`...I'm aware of the arguments in favour of `\newcomman` but I still use `\def`, partly because it is more flexible and partly out of habit.

Comment: @A2009 As you didn't say that this solved your problem perhaps it is not clear from the solution that you can modify the labels on the environments above as you need them. I've added another example to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done directly with these two lines:

```
\newcommand\harabic[1]{\ifnum#1<10\relax0\fi#1}
\renewcommand*{\labelenumi}{\labelprefix\protect\harabic{\theenumi}.}
```

Then, one only need define the leading letter by way of `\labelprefix`.  The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etaremune}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{nosep} % To remove the spacing
\newcommand\harabic[1]{\ifnum#1<10\relax0\fi#1}
\renewcommand*{\labelenumi}{\labelprefix\protect\harabic{\theenumi}.}
\def\labelprefix{M}
\begin{document}
First list

{\def\labelprefix{A}%
\begin{etaremune}[topsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,] 
    \item item 10
    \item item 09
    \item item 08
    \item item 07
    \item item 06
    \item item 05
    \item item 04
    \item item 03
    \item item 02
    \item item 01
\end{etaremune}}

Second list
\begin{enumerate}
    \item item 01
    \item item 02
\end{enumerate}

Third list
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item item 03
    \item item 04
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]