# reverse enumerate and the enumerate package

Tags: numbering

I have been using the enumerate package to list the publications on my 
 cv. The biggest advantage is that counters can be personalized.
 For instance, I can list journal publications using:

```
 \begin{enumerate}[{\bf [J1]}]
 \item
\end{enumerate}
```

This ensures that my papers are listed as:

```
 [J1]
 [J2]
```

and so on.

However, I do want the lists to be reverse numbered. Towards that
 end, I examined the `etaremune` package. It does permit list inversion,
 but I am unable to personalize the counters.

Essentially, I am looking for a hack of `etaremune`, that permits me
 to personalize the counters.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my answer at [Add leading zero to the items listed by a custom etaremune and enumerate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194640/add-leading-zero-to-the-items-listed-by-a-custom-etaremune-and-enumerate/398467#398467).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etaremune}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{nosep} % To remove the spacing
\renewcommand*{\labelenumi}{[\labelprefix\theenumi]}
\def\labelprefix{J}
\begin{document}
First list

\begin{etaremune}[topsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,] 
    \item item 10
    \item item 09
    \item item 08
    \item item 07
    \item item 06
    \item item 05
    \item item 04
    \item item 03
    \item item 02
    \item item 01
\end{etaremune}

\def\labelprefix{R}
Second list
\begin{enumerate}
    \item item 01
    \item item 02
\end{enumerate}

Third list
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item item 03
    \item item 04
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure? I just copied your code.

Comment: And this is what I get:

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xv74ax3el02cy6m/Screenshot%202018-04-27%2010.52.58.png?dl=0

Comment: @KrisUber I get what I get (and cannot access your dropbox from my current location)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the perfect job for the [revnum](https://ctan.org/pkg/revnum) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{revnum}

\begin{document}


\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{J\theenumi.} 

\begin{revnumerate}
\item This is point one
\item This section has two subpoints: 
\item and Point three.
\end{revnumerate}



\end{document}
```

As far as I can see, this package is not included in the common tex distribution, but it can be downloaded from CTAN following the link above.

To install it, run `latex docstrip` and in the subsequent prompts, enter

- infileext: dtx
- outfileext: sty
- options:
- filename: revnum