# Enumerate list with prefix

Tags: lists, context

How do you in ConTeXt the [same as in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108236/enumerate-list-numbers-with-prefix), that is make enumerations list format like this:

- Prefix 1 (content)
- Prefix 2 (content)
- Prefix 3 (content)

Comment: `\startitemize[n][left={Prefix },]`

Comment: @Aditya it does not work because "Prefix" is over the content text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `left` and increase the `width`.

```
\starttext

\startitemize[n][left={\symbol[bullet] Prefix }, width=5em]
\item (content)
\item (content)
\item (content)
\stopitemize

\stoptext
```

[image]

You can also calculate the width automatically, by using the keyword `fit`.  Then you will have to add something to the right however, e.g. `\space`.

```
\starttext

\startitemize[n,fit][left={\symbol[bullet] Prefix },right={\space}]
\item (content)
\item (content)
\item (content)
\stopitemize

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but is it there any way to increase width *automatically*?

Comment: Thanks, finally I did `\startitemize[n,fit][left={Objectius },right={\space}]`